# Adjuntar un pdf a email con php

Tags: php, phpmailer, fpdf

Estimados tengo un problema tengo un archivo `php` el cual crea un `pdf`, le agregue una función para que al crearlo se envié inmediatamente por correo pero no logro adjuntar el `pdf` al correo.

Utilizo fpdf y Phpmailer.

Gracias de antemano.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$pdf->Output('contrareferencia_'.$nomdr_id.'.pdf','I');


function send_mail($to, $from, $subject, $body) {

    $host = "xxxx";
    $username = "xxxxx";
    $password = "xxxxx";

    $cc = "";

        $headers = array ('From' => $from,
          'To' => $to,
          'Cc' => $cc,
          'Subject' => $subject);

          $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
            array ('host' => $host,
              'auth' => true, 'debug' => false,
              'username' => $username,
              'password' => $password,
              'socket_options' => array( 'ssl' => array (
                 'verify_peer' => false,
                 'verify_peer_name' => false,
                 'allow_self_signed' => true
              ))));

       // Creating the Mime message
       $mime = new Mail_mime();

       // Setting the body of the email
       $mime->setTXTBody(strip_tags($body));
       $mime->setHTMLBody($body);



       //Probe agregando asi el archivo pero no me adjunta nada
       //$mime->addAttachment('contrareferencia_'.$nomdr_id.'.pdf','application/pdf');


       $body = $mime->get();
       $headers = $mime->headers($headers);


       $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

     }
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te sale por consola?

Comment: ninguno se envía el correo pero no adjunta nada

Comment: Prueba con la ruta absoluta y en el segundo paramentro el nombre del archivo, por ejemplo `$mime->addAttachment('/home/site1/pdf/contrareferencia_'.$nomdr_id.'.pdf', 'contrareferencia_'.$nomdr_id.'.pdf');`